# For how long will my lost external hard drive store the info in it?

Tags: hdd

2 years ago, I lost an external hard drive with private info on it. I wonder how long the info on it will last -- as I wish that people wouldnt access that info. Thanks

Comment: i am no expert in the matter ... i think that you can probably expect the data to slowly degrade over a few decades ... it all depends on the environment that the drive is in

Comment: Thanks. Where can i contact an expert.?

Comment: what is the point? ... expect the drive to be readable with minor errors for 50 years and act accordingly

Comment: Some Google searches say 5 years, some  10, etc. The info is sensitive to me sadly

Comment: There are plenty of "retro" systems happily booting 20 year old drives. If it's left powered off that tends to extend the life.

Comment: It is more likely that the *interface* will be deprecated before data or hardware degrades.

Answer (score 3):

Data storage usually obeys what I knew in my teens as 'the Law of Sheer Cussedness', but that resists a google search, so Murphy's Law is probably the closest.

Data you want to remain pristine will degrade, data you want to degrade will remain readable.

It's hard to make guarrantees about either case.

In the case of a hard drive, environmental chemical reactions may well be the primary cause of degradation of the data storage layer. While a HD has an active filter to reduce environmental pollutants entering the drive, mostly water vapour, eventually that will become saturated and fail to work. Then temperature cycling pumping will introduce water and other active species into the HD insides, and corrode the discs. Obviously the timescale for that could be millenia, depending on the local environment of the drive.

Sadly, an average is of no interest to you, you want the specific answer for your drive. It could be very brief indeed in an unprotected marine environment. It could be centuries in a dry benign place. So you must **assume your sensitive data will remain readable forever**, and take other steps to mitigate the possibility of its disclosure. Whether that means making efforts to track down the drive, or preparing the people who would think ill of you if it came out, to preparing a number of 'dead cats' to throw on the table for distraction should it come out, to changing your account numbers so the data is no longer relevant.

Comment: Thanks. On average, how long would it take?

Comment: The info is sensitive to me sadly. Some Google searches say 5 years, 10 yrs, etc

Comment: see the additions to my post

Comment: Thank you  very much :/

Comment: Murphy's Law definitely applies. Carefully back up your data, and chances are the backup format will be unsupported (or only $99 ransomware support) by the time you want it (*cough* Microsoft .BKF).  Losing it virtually guarantees it'll be good for a century. Most likely scenario in your case is that nobody can be bothered to try accessing your data, among the billions of junked drives out there.